# Why docker exec doesn't return?

Tags: docker

I am executing the command `docker exec` for example:

```
docker exec reverse ls
```

The first time, it works. Then, it displays the result, but wait indefinitely. I don't understand why.

The `entrypoint` of the container's image is:

```
ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && service nginx && /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm... That's probably because your `ENTRYPOINT` is a little bit anti-pattern.

Normally, one Docker container will only handle one thing which calls `PID=1`, but you give it three things to do and especially `service nginx`. It might cause the container running unexpectedly.

Your command actually is:

```sh
service ssh restart && service nginx && /bin/bash ls
```

Look, it's wired. But there are some tips to check if you really running that container.

a) Remove your `ENTRYPOINT` on Dockerifle first.
b) Running a container with only `/bin/bash` CMD
c) `docker exec -it [CONTAINER_ID] /bin/bash` to enter the container and run the commands to verify if works.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: (Your `ENTRYPOINT` is running a container with an interactive shell, and as soon as that shell exits, the container shuts down.  Also as a side effect it's running a Web server.  You probably want something like `CMD nginx -g 'daemon off;'`, without any `service` and without the interactive shell.)

Comment: Actually I found the problem. Beacause I run a command that restart nginx later. But I don't understand why. So unstead, I just run `service nginx relaod`. That solved my problem

Comment: @DavidMaze, I don't understand why can't I run two services `ssh` and `nginx`. I added the last command `/bin/bash` in order to keep the container running.

Comment: A more typical setup is that a Docker container is a wrapper around a single process.  The container _is_ the process; it doesn't run services _per se_ and you don't ssh into it.  If you need to restart the process, delete and recreate the container.